# Do a pure transitive verb and "interleaved" (for want of the correct name) transitive verb each need their own objects?

Tags: phrase-usage, verbs, phrases

Alice betrayed Bob.

Alice let Bob down.

Alice betrayed and let Bob down, on a strict parsing, implies perhaps that she betrayed Bob down and let him down, even though betraying one down is not a real phrase.

But does the distribution of down have to be so strict, or can it be selective by common sense? So that it can be used to mean that Alice betrayed Bob and let him down?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree 100% with @KateBunting - you could certainly say "I cooked and ate the beans"; you do not have to say "I cooked the beans and ate them."

Comment: @stangdon: ***cook*** and ***eat*** aren't normally phrasal verbs, so they're not really relevant to the question here. Though I suppose we could stretch a point with *I cooked the beans up and [then] I ate the beans up*. If we remove the *first* occurrence of ***up*** there, can we say the *second* occurrence modifies ***cooked*** as well as ***ate***? And if so, what if any nuance of *meaning* might change depending on how many ***up***s there are?

Answer (score 3):

"Let down" is a phrasal verb. The particle (in this case, "down") can usually be placed before or after a noun-phrase direct object. We can therefore avoid the issue entirely by writing:

> Alice betrayed and let down Bob.

This works well because conjuncts (in this case, "betrayed" and "let down") are usually kept together, with no intervening elements. We can replace the series with either conjunct to get a grammatical sentence that maintains the meaning:

> Alice betrayed <strike>and let down</strike> Bob.
> Alice <strike>betrayed and</strike> let down Bob.

Nevertheless, it is common in speech and writing for the particle to be postponed even in a series. Therefore, you may often see:

> Alice betrayed and let Bob down.

If you want to write this in informal contexts, then go ahead; the meaning is clear. In more formal contexts, I recommend keeping items that are not part of the conjuncts (in this case, "Bob") out of the conjuncts.

What if you want to be somewhat formal but find "let down Bob" to sound awkward? Then you can rewrite the sentence. For example, in a comment Kate Bunting suggests:

> Alice betrayed Bob and let him down.